# Using ROS message and python to update text input field in kivy GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, message, kivy, ros

I try to design a GUI to handle stepper motors via ROS, kivy and python. You can find a minimal version of the GUI below. Actually I want to use a ROS message to update a kivy text input field (read only). In the minimal example, pressing the button should transfer the data of the first input field over a local ROS node to the second input field. Actually it seems, that the Callback within the rospy.Subscriber() doesn't enter the Test class.

Thank You for any suggestions!

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Test(BoxLayout):
    text_is = 'text before button press'

    def Pub(self):
        publish = self.ids.test_text_pub.text
        try:
            ROSNode.new_text_is.publish(publish)
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException: pass

class ROSNode(Widget):

    def Callback(publish):
        print(publish.data) #check if Callback has been called
        test.text_is = publish.data

    new_text_is = rospy.Publisher('new_text_is', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber('new_text_is', String, Callback)

    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0

<Test>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            id: test_button
            text: 'publish'
            on_press: root.Pub()

        TextInput:
            id: test_text_pub
            text: 'text after button press'

        TextInput:
            id: test_text_sub
            text: root.text_is
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your text to automatically update, you need to use [Kivy properties](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html).

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
class Test(BoxLayout):
    text_is = StringProperty('text before button press')
```

Kivy properties support data binding, so any updates to the property will propagate through to any bound widget. Binding happens automatically in kv, so when you do this:

```
text: root.text_is
```

..you're telling Kivy that when `root.text_is` is updated, update my `text` also.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I guess it's something with the Callback of the subcriber.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution:

I had to add an on_release event to the button.

```
on_release: test_text_sub.text = root.text_is
```